Papers on signalling + validation?
Looking to see if there's any game theory literature in which 2+ players play a game of incomplete information. One set of (informed) players gives Spence-like signals to the uninformed player(s). The uninformed players then devote resources to learn the validity of those signals.

I would not use the word "validation" here, I personally associate it with econometrics. Currently I have no good suggestion for alternatives. (Spying? Researching? Refining information sets?)

That's likely a better word for it; I'm thinking of a model of, e.g., background checks in gun control. You observe information on the applicant's sanity given the applicant's signal but then use the FBI as a third-party verification system
